# Does Swift has a function like `array.reject` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, swift

Ruby has a very elegant `reject` function for array:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr.reject { |a| a < 3 }     #=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I know swift has a `filter` function. I wonder if Swift has a similar one to `reject`.

Comment: Seems very little to gain over `arr.filter { !(rejectConditional) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extension Array {
    func reject(_ isRejected: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        return self.filter{ !isRejected($0) }
    }
}
```

Now it does.

Even better, you can generalize to any `Sequence`, and even handle throwing predicates:

```
extension Sequence {
    func reject(_ isRejected: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Iterator.Element] {
        return try self.filter{ !(try isRejected($0))}
    }
}
```